# Policy network AlphaGo and transferring to other domains

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

This is not covered very well in their [AlphaGo paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15780/AlphaGo.nature16961.pdf) but I assume that their policy network has a softmax output layer with a node for all the positions on the board, including illegal ones (the one with a stone on the board already). Maybe the illegal ones are basically zero already, I'm uncertain, but I assume they manually put them to zero and then normalize the probabilities. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

To dip my toes into using neural networks for game AI I decided to work on a Backgammon player. I have only implemented a 1D convolutional value network on the board and merged the convolutional layers with the bar and the bearing states. I let random players play a bunch of games, train the model on those game states and let the model play against itself a number of times, tune the model further and iterate this step a number of times. The results are promising so I was looking to add a tree search algorithm similar to AlphaGo.

This is where my question comes from. I would like to use a policy network to guide the exploration through the tree, but I don't know how to represent it. If you don't take the current state in mind, you would have a huge amount of potential states in your last layer of which more than 99.99% would be illegal. If you do keep the current state in mind I don't see how I could train a network on this. Is there any way of building a policy network for Backgammon?

An alternative method would be to use the value network on the potential states that you are able to go to (the network outputs a probability of winning for the active player) and transform those probabilities into a new distribution for exploration, taking in mind exploration versus exploitation.

EDIT: My current representation of actions is the state it would transfer into by doing that action, which means the number of actions over all possible games is enormous.

Comment: As this is likely to require discussion of representation of action choices (so that an action can be selected by the policy), may be work explaining how you are currently representing the available actions in a backgammon move.

Comment: Good point, I will add it to my question

Comment: Am I right in understanding from your description that your action representation is "desired state" and that all possible game states are selectable (99%+ of which are not legal moves - e.g. moving pieces backwards, shuffling them to completely different positions etc, all ignoring the actual dice rolled)

Comment: No, what I'm currently doing is that the Game object passes all possible legal states to the Player object and that the player object evaluates the values of these possible states, and turns them into a probability distribution to sample from in the case of generating training data and picks the highest one in case of playing for real. But the policy network of AlphaGo learns a probability distribution over all moves, which is (seemingly) impossible to do for Backgammon

Comment: OK. I think this is a representation issue (and may affect more than just the structure you are using for actions), but don't have the answer.

Comment: I agree and I'm certainly not married to my current representation, I'm looking for inspiration of how to tackle this (I'm not even convinced that it can be tackled)